# I cannot place an Oil Well despite having met all the prereqs?

Tags: simcity-2013

[image: http://i.imgur.com/tVYOqWq.jpg]

Despite having met all the prereqs (as far as I'm aware) I cannot place the Oil Well in this space. Clicking doesn't show an error, it just doesn't build the Oil Well. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't tell from your screenshot but are you trying to place it in an open area? You _must_ place it next to a road.

Comment: Yeah, it's in a completely open area with open road space, unzoned.  http://i.imgur.com/5qszKCV.jpg

Comment: I've had a similar issue with other buildings, most notably Parks.. They just won't plop even though there doesn't appear to be anything preventing it.

Comment: i think it is a bug. placement results in nothing. Move placement to a slightly different position and it works. Has happened with parks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer to your problem is the terrain is curving down, I had the same problem with my recycling center as it appears there is room but it was curved down to the sea.

The trick with oil wells that may not be apparent if you haven't done much with them is that you can create feeder roads to the well heads.  So find a place where you can plop the well, then build roads to the pumps.

Keep this in mind as the oil depletes under one pump, you can add additional pumps.